# The number of moved files robocopy

Tags: batch-file, cmd, robocopy

I need to get the number of files which I moved with robocopy. I've tried a lot of methods, but I need exactly the number which I see in the cmd line after `robocopy` has finished the process and shows me the result.

> Copied files - x

How can I get the value of `x`? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
robocopy [Whatever Options] | findstr "Copied files"
```

will get you down to just the final report.

You just need to parse out for the actual number, which you can do with a `for` loop.

I would help you more, but ***you did not show any code.***

---

When I run robocopy, the output I get looks like:

```
              Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
   Dirs :         1         0         1         0         0         0
  Files :        12        12         0         0         0         0
  Bytes :   49.91 m   49.91 m         0         0         0         0
  Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
```

This is very different from your report that you see `Copied Files - X`.

---

I think this is getting close to what you want:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%a in ('robocopy [options] ^| findstr /C:Files ') do (
    set num=%%a )

echo Files That Got Copied: %num%
```

*(lightly tested, it seems to work)*

Comment: Thanks for the reply.If I got correctly It is possible to use findstr just to search in files, so I have to write a log file with robocopy's report firstly and then try to find my phrase there. Is that right? Which code would you like to see? I have just string with robocopy.

Comment: I just ran Robocopy on my machine, and it does **not** include the output `Copied files - X`.  What options are you passing to robocopy?  What exact output are you seeing?

Comment: I get the same, but in Russian. Sorry for that. So I need to get the number 12 in your case, files which are copied.  Setlocal enabledelayedextantion robocopy [options]| for /f "tokens=4 delims=....... " %%a in ('findstr /I "Files" ) do set num=%%a echo !num!   I see in cmd set num=12 but actually it doesn't change when i use it after. Thanks.

Comment: Do not post code in comments.  That is very difficult to read.
Edit your answer to include your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a log then you have to use the `/log` option. Otherwise, you can see the number of your copied files as long as you do NOT use the `/njs` option.

```
for /f "tokens=3 skip=1" %%a in (
 'robocopy /L . " nothing ..//" ^|findstr /rc:":  *[0-9][0-9]* "'
)do echo %%a
```

Comment: Sorry but I still can't get the idea. Your code returns me echo ':'. Moreover I haven't got how robocopy can work in cycle for. I want to move files with robocopy (pretty easy) and then write the number of copied files in the variable. This number I have to get from robocopy's report. Sry for no code. I am forced to use my smartphone